# non-professional C# application deployment Windows 10

Tags: c#, deployment

I've been asked to create an small application for a friend. 
As a quick test, I've send him the executable (C# wpf) which alarmed his virusscanner all over.
'It was a program downloaded from the internet which should not be launched'.

It's a logical reaction but I don't have experience with the professional standard way to fix this. What would be the best free approach for a C# WPF application for Windows 10?

Comment: Maybe signing would help...

Comment: Can I do this without additional costs from buying a certificate or something?